# New Silverlight app doesn't generate XAP

Tags: silverlight, xap

I have created a new Silverlight app and it created a XAp file under the CLientBin on the Server side.

However after copying an existing project into the same folder and adding it to the solution, the XAP file is not being generated for the this assembly.

What am I missing?

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Do not attempt to modify your project/solution files manually unless you know exactly what you are doing :)**

Adding it to the solution is not enough. You need to make a Silverlight relationship between the website and your Silverlight application.

- Right-click on your website project and select `Properties`.
- Choose the `Silverlight Applications` tab on the left side
- Press `Add...`
- Leave `Use an existing Silverlight project in the solution` checked and select the project you want to add from the `Project` dropdown.
- Leave `Add a test page that references the control` checked if you want a separate test page for your application.
- Press `Add` and you are done.

The website will now build your Silverlight application and include the output Xap file in its ClientBin folder.

[image: Add Silverlight Application dialog]

Answer (score 2):

You need to update your project files:

The Silverlight project file contains a parameter indicating a server project:

```
<LinkedServerProject>..\SLClient.Web\SLClient.Web.csproj</LinkedServerProject>
```

The Web application project file contains a list of the Silverlight application projects:

```
<SilverlightApplicationList>{97E56891-B97D-4588-8262-BFB7DC5FD6D2}|..\SLClient\SLClient.csproj|ClientBin|False</SilverlightApplicationList>
```

This value tells MSBuild to copy the XAP in the clientBin directory.

Take note of the supplied GUID. It can be obtained from the Silverlight app csproj file:

```
<ProjectGuid>{97E56891-B97D-4588-8262-BFB7DC5FD6D2}</ProjectGuid>
```

You can open the project files in Visual Studio by first unloading the project in the context menu.

Comment: You can also do this through the property pages in Visual Studio, which is *probably* (!!) somewhat safer.

Comment: Thank you, I suppose I remember an old age when it wasn't in the property pages ;)

Comment: Accidentally down-voted so, want to up-vote it back. :( sorry